# In my ruby on rails app I called render text: nil which returns space mark " "

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript

In my `BillsController` I wrote

```
def bill_info
   path = Path.find_by_bill_id(params[:id]).try(:url)
   render text: path
end
```

and in my view I wrote a `get` method to call `bill_info`

using coffee script

```
$.get ("/bills/<%= @bill.id %>/bill_info"), {}, (data)->
```

and it turns out that if `path == nil` it will return `data` that is equal to space mark " ", I find it difficult to understand, will someone please be kind enough to tell me why?

Thanks

Comment: this is non maintainable: create your url using rails helpers, put it in a data attribute

Comment: When you render text in rails, you don't need a view file. It will just display the text returned. How does it recognize coffeescript?

Comment: I used this gem https://github.com/rails/coffee-rails, I know this is bad coding but I'm just curious why it would return a space mark.